# I'm trying to save a text file from Excel using VBA. The data in the text file has quote comma quote

Tags: vba, excel

How do I go about making this happen? I need the final result to look like this: [image]

I've tried several variations of the following, but nothing is working:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim FilePath As String
  Dim CellData As String

  StockCode = Range("H1").Value
  JobNumber = Range("H2").Value
  Comma = ","
  TheDateTime = Month(Now) & Day(Now) & Year(Now) & Hour(Now) & Minute(Now) & Second(Now)


  CellData = StockCode
  CellData = CellData & """,""" & JobNumber & """,""" & TheDateTime
  FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\TextFile.txt"

  Open FilePath For Output As #1

  Write #1, CellData
  CellData = ""

  Close #1

End Sub
```

Which gives the following:
[image]

How do I get the "data","data","data" format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Write #` statement inserts commas between items and quotation marks around strings as they are written to the file. You don't have to put explicit delimiters in the list. See here: [Write # Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/writestatement)

Try `Write #1, StockCode, JobNumber, TheDateTime` instead of concatenating all of them into `CellData`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to this and didn't realize it worked that way. Thanks for providing the correct solution and documentation.